# Instagram poste embedding not working properly

Tags: html, angular, instagram, embedded-resource

Basically i'm building a website in Angular and I was trying to incorporate the instagram posts of a tattoo studio. The page is open and the account is a commercial one, but when I try to embed this happens.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkphe.png)

Instead of letting me visualize the post i can only follow the link.

I tried to embed photos of various accounts, all open ones and from very famous people, but the same thing happens

I'm thinking to try to use the instagram api to retrieve post's data

Comment: can you create a stackblitz post with your code (embedding code)? would like to see what and how you are trying to embed and would love to help by editing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Storytellerr i'm just copying and pasting the code that is given from instagram when you select the option to embed the post. It's the import of a script (instagram/embed.js) and the html for the img